# is it worth rewriting my code in cython?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cython

I have a program in python using numpy and scipy.
adding cython in it will be a time taking process as there are many changes in data types

The cprofile of it looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2J9O.jpg

Most of the time (73% ) is used up by `<scipy.integrate_odepack.odeint>`
My question basically is, does using cython speed up this function(maybe by faster calling) and the rest.
This function is called ~10^6 times in this example.
And if so, How much speed up can I expect?
I consider pursuing this if speed up is atleast 4x to 5x

note:

If the information provided is insufficient, please comment below and I'd be glad to provide

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well half of the time of `<scipy.integrate_odepack.odeint>` is being spent inside `dx_dv` and `dx_du` these look like they're python functions. These are functions you could target especially if they are complex.

One thing to bear in mind is that if the slow down is just because of the `calling overhead * number of calls` then I wouldn't expect things to improve much. That overhead won't disappear, in fact it might be made more complex. Instead of SciPy C -> Python, you'll be doing SciPy C -> Python -> your C.

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph. However, the calling sequence Fortran (not C!) -> Python -> C isn't necessarily slower than Fortran -> Python.

Comment: actually, look at the image again... `dX_dv` and `dX_du` are functions inside his `GRScalar.py` file. `<scipy.integrate_odepack.odeint>` has nothing to do with these functions... as these are something that the OP is calling...  Of course, having a sample of the source code that uses these methods would greatly clear up what is happening.

Comment: @g19fanatic: I'm not familiar with this profiler, but I took it that `dX_dv` is called by `odeint` and assumed that it's the OP's callback.

Comment: there isnt a `dX_dv` call anywhere in scipy's code for this. `dX_dv` is the function (I am assuming) that the OP passes into `odeint` to calculate the derivative. Checkout https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/integrate/odepack.py  This whole thing could be 'sped up' by writing CPython (possibly Cython) Modules for the dX functions but nothing can be done to `scipy` to make it inherently faster (which was the original question, not necessarily the correct question).

Comment: Yes, dX_du and dX_dv are python functions that calculate the derivatives. I am writing them in cython. Thanks!

Comment: @larsmans: Fortran <-> C: You're right be it doesn't make any difference as far as I know. I wasn't sure about the calling sequence complexity causing any problems. It's something I'd have to experiment with, but I wanted to alert the OP that there *might* be an issue.

Comment: @g19fanatic: Yep, I saw that. They're callbacks if I've understood the documentation for that function correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Chances are you're not going to see much (if any) improvement. SciPy (and even more specific the code you're most interested in, `odeint`) is already a CPython module(written in Fortran), not just python.

If this were a python-only function call, then writing it in Cython (which can be easier than writing a full blown CPython module, though personally I'd write a c or c++ dll and call it using ctypes...) would increase your performance. But probably not in this situation.